# Array multiplication with counter array

Tags: java, arrays, pascals-triangle

I have been doing pascal's triangle for a homework and I have already got the entire code for printing the triangle ad in the way I want it. Our teacher asked us to show on every row the result of the multiplications of the numbers inside that row; for example:on row 1 it should print 1, in row 2 print 1, in row 3 print 2, in row 4 print 9 and so on...
I have written kind of like counter array to do this but it doesn't seem to work, here I leave you my code so you can check it out and see if you can help me. The counter array is c[] by the way. Thank you very much!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class class1_080414_Rodrigo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String fila;
        int f, a=0, b=0;
        //
        fila=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Until which line of the triangle would you like to prnt?");
        f=Integer.parseInt(fila);
        //
        if (f<0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You cannot type negative numbers.");
        }
        int triangulo [][] = new int[f][f];
        int c [] = new int [f];
        //
        for (a=0;a<f;a++){
            for (b=0; b<f; b++){
                triangulo[a][b] = 0;
            }
        }
        for (a=0;a<f;a++){
            triangulo[a][0] = 1;
        }
        for (a=1;a<f;a++) {
            for (b=1;b<f;b++) {
                triangulo[a][b] = triangulo[a-1][b-1] + triangulo[a-1][b];
            }
        } 
        for (a=0;a<f;a++) {
            for(b=0;b<=a;b++) {
                if (b==0){
                    System.out.format("%"+(80-a)+"s", "");
                }
                c[a]=1;
                c[a]=c[a]*triangulo[a][b];
                System.out.print(triangulo[a][b]+" ");
            }
            System.out.print(" ="+c[a]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be Brazilian. Try http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

You keep resetting c[a] back to 1.  That should come out of the b loop.

Change

```
        for (a=0;a<f;a++) {
        for(b=0;b<=a;b++) {
            if (b==0){
                System.out.format("%"+(80-a)+"s", "");
            }
            c[a]=1;
            c[a]=c[a]*triangulo[a][b];
            System.out.print(triangulo[a][b]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print(" ="+c[a]);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

to

```
    for (a=0;a<f;a++) {
        c[a]=1;
        for(b=0;b<=a;b++) {
            if (b==0){
                System.out.format("%"+(80-a)+"s", "");
            }
            c[a]=c[a]*triangulo[a][b];
            System.out.print(triangulo[a][b]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print(" ="+c[a]);
        System.out.println();
    }
```